# Django forloop not indexing correctly

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am populating a table from a python list passed through a django tag:

```
{% for alt in altList %}
          <td align="center">
            {{alt.1}}</br>
            {{alt.2}}</br>
            {{alt.3}}</br>
            {{alt.4}}</br>
            <input type="hidden" value={{alt.0}}/>
          </td>
{% endfor %}
```

This works correctly, but the list is randomly generated in python and I need to maintain the same list if the user of my form makes an error. I included a hidden field that stores the current list. The trouble is that, when I have an error, it does not run the loop as I expect.

The working input list is shown as:

```
[(196, u&#39;hydro&#39;, u&#39;25&#39;, u&#39;735&#39;, u&#39;7&#39;), (266, u&#39;coal&#39;, u&#39;140&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;), (372, u&#39;hydro&#39;, u&#39;260&#39;, u&#39;990&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;), (383, u&#39;solar&#39;, u&#39;510&#39;, u&#39;990&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;)]
```

When I have a list from the previous post I would like to use, it is also shown as follows in the console:

```
[(196, u&#39;hydro&#39;, u&#39;25&#39;, u&#39;735&#39;, u&#39;7&#39;), (266, u&#39;coal&#39;, u&#39;140&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;), (372, u&#39;hydro&#39;, u&#39;260&#39;, u&#39;990&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;), (383, u&#39;solar&#39;, u&#39;510&#39;, u&#39;990&#39;, u&#39;63&#39;)]
```

It appears to have the same formatting, so I'm not sure what the issue could be; however, in the second case it parses very differently and gives me a long list that includes things like ''/' as elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the list's random order in user's session or I think it's a  better choice to shuffle in the client side through javascript.

Comment: That works. It's much easier to store the list of ids than the whole list because I am pulling the entries from a database table.